# How to change this code to not printing unused coin=0?

Tags: python

I am trying to build a function that after people entering the amount of money, it will show the minimum number of coins or notes that they need. But this there any methods for me to change it so that it will not print the name and the number of the unused coin? (as a beginner) Thanks for helping! (Will it be possible to deal with it by using for loop?)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping a variable for every demonmation, keep a dict and update key: val based on the denominations used. See the code

```
amount=int(input('Enter an amount: '))

denominations = dict()

print('Total number of notes/coins=')

if amount>=1000:
    denominations['1000'] = amount//1000
    amount%=1000    
if amount>=500:
    denominations['500'] = amount//500
    amount= amount%500
if amount>=100:
    denominations['100'] = amount//100
    amount= amount%100
if amount>=50:
    denominations['50'] = amount//50
    amount= amount%50    
if amount>=20:
    denominations['20'] = amount//20
    amount= amount%20    
if amount>=10:
    denominations['10'] = amount//10
    amount= amount%10
if amount>=5:
    denominations['5'] = amount//5
    amount= amount%5   
if amount>=2:
    denominations['2'] = amount//2
    amount= amount%2    
if amount>=1:
    denominations['1'] = amount//1

for key, val in denominations.items():
    print(f"{key}: {val}")


Enter an amount: 523
Total number of notes/coins=
500: 1
20: 1
2: 1
1: 1
```

You can reduce the number of lines of code if you use a simple logic like shown below,

```
def find_denominations():
    
    amount=int(input('Enter an amount: '))
    
    denominations = dict()
    
    DENOMINATIONS = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
       
    print('Total number of notes/coins=')
    
    for d in DENOMINATIONS:
        if amount >= d:
            denominations[d] = amount // d
            amount %= d

    for key, val in denominations.items():
        print(f"{key}: {val}")
```

Comment: denominations is a dict and the code is iterating the dict and picking up key and value from the dict and printing it out.

Answer (score 0):

A similiar implementation to Sreerams using a while loop instead a for loop:

```python
amount = int(input("Enter an amount: "))

counter = amount
pos = 0
notes = [1000, 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
output = []

while counter > 0:

    remainder = counter % notes[pos]
    sub = counter - remainder
    num = int(sub / notes[pos])
    counter -= sub
    output.append({notes[pos]: num})
    pos += 1

print("Total number of notes/coins=")

for r in output:
    for k,v in r.items():
        if v > 0:
            print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

Please note Sreerams code is superior to mine, it's easier to read and would be more performant at scale.

Answer (score 0):

Loop can be used iterate through a list of notes and inside the loop, if any note is found to be counted, that can be printed.

```
notes=[1000,500,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

amount=int(input('Enter an amount: '))

print('Total number of notes/coins=')

for notesAmount in notes:
    if amount>=notesAmount:
       notesCount=amount//notesAmount
       amount%=notesAmount
       if notesCount>0:
          print(notesAmount, ":", notesCount)
```